# python regular expression to remove specific sub_string from the string

Tags: regex, python-3.x

i want to remove all  `sort_by=<string>` from the variable `get_params`.

the get_params will be either `?sort_by=name&role=user` or 
`?gender=male&sort_by=name_desc&role=user` or `'?sort_by=name'`

and i want something output like this

i tried this

```
re.sub("^sort_by=&*$",r'', get_params)
```

but its not working .

i looked into many answers in stackoverflow but i couldnt do it

Comment: Try `re.sub(r'\?sort_by=[^&]*$|(?<=[?&])sort_by=[^&]*&', '', get_params)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for helping me. if the variable is `?age=24&sort_by=fullname&gender=male` then the result is `?age=24&&gender=male` double & is comming . Is there any way to remove it .

Comment: My comment has been updated. Actually, I see I need to make last `&` optional. Use `re.sub(r'\?sort_by=[^&]*$|(?<=[?&])sort_by=[^&]*&?', '', get_params)`. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/81fzfK/3).

Comment: i really apprectiate your help ...thanks a loot... if you dont mind could you please explain a bit about this regex ..

Comment: sorry @WiktorStribiżew  i got it from the demo link.. thanks a lot.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
[?&]sort_by=[^&]*$|(?<=[?&])sort_by=[^&]*&
```

to replace with an empty string. See the [regex demo online](https://regex101.com/r/fcwLae/1).

It matches

- `[?&]` - a `?` or `&`
- `sort_by=` - a literal substring
- `[^&]*` - 0+ chars other than `&`
- `$` - end of string.
- `|` - or
- `(?<=[?&])` - a location preceded with `?` or `&`
- `sort_by=` - a literal substring
- `[^&]*` - 0+ chars other than `&`
- `&` - a `&` char.

A [Python demo](https://ideone.com/s3PFIN):

```
key_to_remove = r'sort_by'
rx = r'[?&]{0}=[^&]*$|(?<=[?&]){0}=[^&]*&'.format(key_to_remove)
tests = ['?sort_by=name&role=user','?gender=male&sort_by=name_desc&role=user','?sort_by=name','?age=24&sort_by=fullname&gender=male','?age=24&sort_by=fullname']
for test in tests:
    print(test + " => " + re.sub(rx, "", test))
```

Output:

```
?sort_by=name&role=user                  => ?role=user
?gender=male&sort_by=name_desc&role=user => ?gender=male&role=user
?sort_by=name                            => 
?age=24&sort_by=fullname&gender=male     => ?age=24&gender=male
?age=24&sort_by=fullname                 => ?age=24
```